# Htaccess get parameter from.url and redirect to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I redirect from, for example:

```
https://www.example.com/?user=user1
```

to:

```
https://user1.example.com
```

Comment: Not sure why did someone down-voted this!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)user=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.domain.com [R=301,L]
```